# Is there a way to only allow one TRUE in a SwiftData "table"?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

Imagine I have a SwiftData @Model like so:

```
@Model
final class Semester {
    // other properties
    var isCurrent: Bool

    // init here
}
```

I would also have a Toggle that directly interacts with this property like so:

```
Toggle("Current", isOn: $semester.isCurrent)
```

The question is:
When I toggle one semester to be current, is there a way to reverse the values of all other semester.isCurrent? Basically, allow only one semester to be current. I am thinking a calculated property, maybe?

Comment: A possible solution is a custom Binding – which works like a `didSet` property observer – to reset the rest of the data records. Or, much more efficient, keep a reference to the previous record to reset `isCurrent` in the `set` scope of the Binding.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to control how the property is updated by making the `set` private and instead have a function that sets the property to true and everyone else to false.

```
private(set) var isCurrent: Bool = false
//...

func markAsCurrent() throws {
    guard let modelContext = self.modelContext else { return }

    try modelContext.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Semester>(predicate: #Predicate<Semester> { $0.isCurrent == true }))
        .forEach { $0.isCurrent = false }

    self.isCurrent = true
}
```

To make it possible to use this function like a boolean property for instance in a `Toggle` we can add a transient property

```
@Transient
var isCurrentTogge: Bool {
    get {
        isCurrent
    }
    set {
        if newValue { try? markAsCurrent() }
    }
}
```

Actually to take this one step further it is probably best to make the original property completely private to avoid a confusing public interface (with two ways to access the same underlying property) and rename it so that our transient property can use the "public" name we want to use in the rest of our code

```
private var isCurrentStored: Bool = false

//...

@Transient
var isCurrent: Bool { ... }
```

Comment: I like this answer. I used a variation of this to fit my needs. I am curious how you personally would implement this using SwiftUI's Toggle. Care to show?

Comment: @alexspurlock25 Was this answer helpful?